# bought or had bought in this case

Tags: past-tense

It was around this time that top shelf collector/seller Jeff Gold had made contact with Rob Gretton’s partner Lesley Gilbert and ***bought*** some of his record collection from her. Through Jeff, I was able to contact Lesley

Henry Rollins text written for the reissue of the panik "it won't sell"

I think this one is past simple, am I right or is it past perfect (had was already written   so no need to write it a second time). Can we choose between these two, the more plausible

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could use *had bought* there. But in speech (or informal writing), English speakers often don't use the more complicated construction when the temporal relationships are already clear.

Comment: so for you this is past perfect , so it means that before this time Jeff had already contacted Lesley and had bought her collection

Comment: I didn't see the possibility of the other reading. I can see that it is possible, but to me it seems less likely - I'm not sure why.